# Karp hardness of testing for homomorphisms to a fixed non-bipartite graph

Tags: np-complete, np-hard, np

**Description**: Suppose that we are given a *fixed* **non-bipartite** graph $H$. A graph $G$ is *loopless surjectively homomorphic* to $H$ if there exists a **loopless surjective homomorphism** $\varphi:V(G)\to V(H)$ such that:

> For every $u,v\in V(G)$,  $(\varphi(u)=\varphi(v))\lor(uv\in E(G)\implies\varphi(u)\varphi(v)\in E(H))$.

*Note that we do not allow loops and multiple edges. This is just because $H$ is  a fixed simple undirected graph. So, mapping to the same vertices is good but remember to map to every vertex of $H$. This also does not put constraint on those vertices mapped to the same $H$-vertex. By standard definition, without a loop at that $H$-vertex, the set of $G$-vertices mapped to it needs to be an independent set.*

We want to decide whether a given graph $G$ is **loopless surjectively homomorphic** to $H$. Note that for each fixed non-bipartite $H$, we have a decision problem, denoted by $\mathrm{HOMOMORPHIC}_H$.

Formally, for every fixed (i.e. not part of the input) non-bipartite graph $H$, $\mathrm{HOMOMORPHIC_H}$ is defined as below:

> **Input**: An undirected graph $G$
>
> **Output**: **YES** if $G$ is loopless surjectively homomorphic to $H$, otherwise **NO**

We want to know the computational complexity of this problem.

Comment: Do you want to know whether there exists a (non-bipartite) graph for which the problem is NP-complete, or do you want to know the exact complexity for each choice for H?

Comment: Normally, the requirement would be $uv \in E(G) \Rightarrow \varphi(u)\varphi(v) \in E(H)$. Are you sure your definition of homomorphism is correct? (see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_homomorphism)

Comment: If I read your current definition correctly, any graph $G$ is homomorphic to $H$. (Pick an arbitrary vertex $h \in V(H)$ and let $\varphi(v) = h$ for all $v\in V(G)$)?

Comment: If the current version still has some unwanted feature, please comment to let me know.

Comment: Well I cannot say for sure whether it has unwanted features (because I do not know what you want to define exactly), but I think at least the problem is now non-trivial, which is good. Can you explain why you want to allow $\varphi(u) = \varphi(v)$?

Comment: $H$ is fixed. $G$ is the input. So for large enough $G$, it is necessarily to have $\varphi(u)=\varphi(v)$ for some distinct $u,v\in V(G)$. And we don't want any loops in $H$. Admittedly, this is not **algebraic**.

Comment: By your current definition, if $H$ is a clique, any graph $G$ with at least as many vertices as $H$ is "loopless surjectively homomorphic" to $H$. Is this desirable? Interesting question what the complexity would be for other choices of $H$ (I suspect this is not known)

Comment: That is kind of what I was afraid of.

Comment: @kne It's just "Add a loop to every vertex of $H$ -- is there a surjective homomorphism?" I don't think it has much in common with graph minors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is more easily phrased as follows.  You have a fixed non-bipartite, reflexive graph $H$ (reflexive = a loop on every vertex) and you want to know the complexity of deciding whether there is a surjective homomorphism (in the usual sense) from an input graph $G$ to $H$.

As far as I can see, this question is open.

- The problem is trivially in **P** when $H$ is a clique, since every $G$ with $|V(G)|\geq|V(H)|$ has a surjective homomorphism.
- Golovach *et al.* [1] have shown, for each four-vertex $H$, that the problem is either in **P** or is **NP**-complete (including bipartite cases, and allowing loops on any **strict** subset of the vertices).

I don't know of anything else with loops on all vertices.

---

[1] P. A. Golovach, M. Johnson, B. Martin, D. Paulusma, A. Stewart, *Surjective $H$-colouring: new hardness results*. [ArXiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.02188.pdf), 2017.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out in the comments, your definition of homomorphism is highly unusual. In particular, any function whose image is a single vertex is a homomorphism by your definition, thus trivializing the decision problem. The usual definition is as follows:

A homomorphism from $G$ to $H$ is a function $\varphi:V(G)\to V(H)$ such that for all $uv\in E(G)$ we have $\varphi(u)\varphi(v)\in E(H)$.

For the usual definition, the problem is known to be NP-complete for every non-bipartite $H$. The reference (according to Wikipedia) is Hell, Pavol; Nešetřil, Jaroslav (1990), "On the complexity of H-coloring", Journal of Combinatorial Theory Series B, 48 (1): 92–110. (For bipartite $H$, on the other hand, there is a homomorphism if and only if $G$ is bipartite. Thus the decision problem is just bipartiteness of $G$, which is in PTIME.)

A few other notion are somewhat halfway between your definition and the usual one:

- A strong homomorphism from $G$ to $H$ is a function $\varphi:V(G)\to V(H)$ such that for all $u,v\in V(G)$ we have $uv\in E(G)$ if and only if $\varphi(u)\varphi(v)\in E(H)$.
- An embedding from $G$ in $H$ is an injective homomorphism, that is a homomorphism $\varphi$ such that for all $u,v\in V(G)$ with $u\not=v$ we have $\varphi(u)\not=\varphi(v)$.
- An induced subgraph mapping is an injective strong homomorphism.

[EDIT]

For each of these variants, the problem is in PTIME for fixed $H$.
When injectivity is required, one can reject an instance if $|V(G)|>|V(H)|$, so only a finite set of graphs remains. For strong homomorphisms, we can have $\varphi(v)=\varphi(w)$ only if $v$ and $w$ have the same neighbours. Hence after some polynomial time preprocessing, we can again assume injectivity.

Comment: That would be a surprise if testing for being strongly homomorphic to a graph $H$ with only $3$ vertices is $NP$ complete. Note that that is testing if $G$ can be partitioned into $3$ independent sets each two of which form a biclique.

Comment: If you allow the fixed graph $H$ to have loops (which are not allowed in our problem here), then instead of $3$ independent sets, you may have something like $1$ independent set and $2$ cliques, each two of them form a biclique.

Comment: Anyway, I have to admit that breaking the algebraic nature of these kinds of problems seems to push us into *an unknown universe*.

Comment: Yes, my memory of the strong homomorphism case was faulty. Now corrected.